# Linq-to-SQL throwing NullReferenceException despite checking for null arguments

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I'm trying to write Linq-To-SQL queries in LinqPad to help migrate users from old tables to new tables. Part of this migration is storing all addresses in a separate table. I'm using the following query to determine if a user's address exists in the new table (so I don't have duplicate entries):

```
var addresses = from a in Addresses where ((u.Street_address == null && a.Street1 == null) || (u.Street_address != null && a.Street1 != null && a.Street1.ToLower() == u.Street_address.ToLower())) 
                                && ((a.City == null && u.City == null) || (a.City != null && u.City != null && a.City.ToLower() == u.City.ToLower())) 
                                && ((a.State == null && u.State == null) || (a.State != null && u.State != null && a.State.ToLower() == u.State.ToLower())) 
                                && ((a.Zip == null && u.Zipcode == null) || (a.Zip != null && u.Zipcode != null && a.Zip.ToLower() == u.Zipcode.ToLower()))
                                select a;
```

Here, 'u' represents an old user. Some addresses in the old table contain null entries for the Street_address, City, State, and/or Zipcode. Also, some addresses are duplicates, except for casing (hence the ToLower()).

Despite checking for null parameters in the query, I still get a NullReferenceException if any of the user's address parameters are null.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better way to accomplish what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Hmmm, looks like this is more complex than I originally thought. Turns out String.Equals with a StringComparison overload is [not supported by Linq-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882672.aspx).  But, the fact that you get the error means that Linq-to-SQL is trying to take the entire expression and turn it into SQL. Which in turn means that all comparisons will happen according to the native collation of the database-- which by default is case-insensitive.  So even though Linq-to-SQL won't support case-insensitive comparisons, you probably don't need case-insensitive comparisons since you can rely on SQL Server doing them by default.

So, provided you haven't changed the collation of your string columns in your table from case-insensitive (the default) to case-sensitive, the following code should work:

```
var addresses = from a in Addresses 
                where String.Equals (u.Street_address, a.Street1)
                      && String.Equals (u.City, a.City)
                      && String.Equals (u.State, a.State)
                      && String.Equals (u.ZipCode, a.Zip)
                select a;
```

It's possible this may work too:

```
var addresses = from a in Addresses 
                where u.Street_address == a.Street1
                      && u.City == a.City
                      && u.State == a.State
                      && u.ZipCode == a.Zip
                select a;
```

But, based on my reading of [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882669.aspx) (excerpted below), I suspect that only using `==` (instead of String.Equals() may not work) :

> **Null semantics**
>
> LINQ to SQL does not
>   impose null comparison semantics on
>   SQL. Comparison operators are
>   syntactically translated to their SQL
>   equivalents. For this reason, the
>   semantics reflect SQL semantics that
>   are defined by server or connection
>   settings. For example, two null values
>   are considered unequal under default
>   SQL Server settings, but you can
>   change the settings to change the
>   semantics. LINQ to SQL does not
>   consider server settings when it
>   translates queries.
>
> A comparison with the literal null is
>   translated to the appropriate SQL
>   version (is null or is not null).

In other words, if I'm reading this MSDN text correctly, it sounds like Linq-to-SQL translates `==` into `=` in T-SQL, while (as your experiment showed) String.Equals is translated correctly as a check for `IS NULL` followed by a check using `=`.  If you have a chance to test just `==`, I'd be interested to see whether Linq-to-SQL emits the `IS NULL` checks or not.

Given the complexity here (Linq-to-SQL translating C# into SQL, and results back to C#) your best bet in cases like this is to try multiple variations (e.g. == vs. Equals()) and pick the one that works, since there are enough moving parts that it's hard to anticipate ahead of time which variation will work best.

**OLD ANSWER (ignore this):**

Consider using the static [`String.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) method instead of `==` and `ToLower()`.  You'll avoid the null-reference problems (and simplify your code) because nulls are OK to pass into that method and it supports a case-insensitive check.

```
var addresses = from a in Addresses 
                where String.Equals (u.Street_address, a.Street1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      && String.Equals (u.City, a.City, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      && String.Equals (u.State, a.State, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                      && String.Equals (u.ZipCode, a.Zip, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                select a;
```

Although if your database is already case-insensitive, depending on how Linq-to-SQL splits the work between SQL and C# code, you may not need the insensitivity check at all-- although if it were me, I'd rather be safe and enure you always enforce the case check.

Comment: String.Equals doesn't seem to work with Linq-to-SQL. You get the following exception: "NotSupportedException: Method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)' has no supported translation to SQL." I also tried using String.IsNullOrEmpty() for the null check, but I got the same error message

Comment: take a look at my revised answer-- the error message you got is a good sign, it means that the solution is probably even easier! :-)

Comment: Thanks!!! That worked. What's really interesting is after looking at the generated SQL queries, String.Equals() generates queries similar to what I had originally without the ToLower() method calls. Basically, it checks for not null, then checks for equality. So just using u.Street_address == a.Street1 is not enough, you have to also check for null. I believe that's because SQL cannot compare NULL using =? What I don't understand is why == is not being evaluated as String.Equals()?

Comment: Did you try using just ==, without the ToLower() or null check?  If so, did Linq-to-SQL correctly emit the "check if both null" check into SQL?  If not, that sounds like a bug in Linq-to-SQL's translation of C# semantics to SQL and back again.

Comment: Actually, reading MSDN (see link and excerpt in my just-revised answer above) it looks like the lack of IS NULL checking my be "by design" when using ==.  It may be questionable design, though... :-)

Comment: I did try using just == initially. Then I decided to try the IsLower() because I was getting duplicates and I thought it was a casing problem. The == operator translates to the = operator, but String.Equals() translates to "check if both null, then =". However, in normal C# == translates to String.Equals(). I can understand why you'd want the difference, but it's certainly confusing if you're used to the C# behavior. Finally, thank you for the MSDN article!